# Problema com select em tabela com relacionamento many to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
public class Pedido
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProdutosPedido> ProdutosPedidos { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    }

public class Produto
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public string Valor { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProdutosPedido> ProdutosPedidos { get; set; }
    }

 public class ProdutosPedido
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProdutosPedidoId { get; set; }

        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }

        public int PedidoId { get; set; }

        public int Quantidade { get; set; }

        public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

        public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }

        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Consigo salvar o Pedido com os Produtos sem problema algum, mas quero fazer uma tabela master details para mostrar o Pedido com os seus Produtos.

Segue código da Controller

```
public ActionResult TodosOsPedidos()
        {
            var pedidos = _db.ProdutosPedidos.Include("Pedido").Include("Produto").Where(x => x.Pedido.Id == 2);
            return View(pedidos);
        }
```

Código da View:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 85px">
                Pedido Nº
            </th>
            <th style="text-align: left">
                Solicitante
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Data do Pedido
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Atualizado Em
            </th>

            <th style="width: 65px"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PedidoId)
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pedido.Franqueado.NomeFantasia)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pedido.CreateDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pedido.UpdateDate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Produtos", new { @id = item.PedidoId })" title="Editar" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary tool">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="@item.PedidoId" title="Excluir" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tool delete-produto">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%"  colspan="5">
                <h5>Produtos</h5>
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Descrição</th>
                            <th>Quantidade</th>
                            <th>Valor Unitário</th>
                            <th>Valor Total</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Quantidade)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Produto.Valor)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Quero deixar como o exemplo abaixo:

```
Nº Pedido     Solicitante          Data Criacao   Data Atualizacao
      1            Fornecedor 01        23/05/2014        27/05/2014
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descrição     Qntd     Valor Uni     Valor Total         Status       #
Produto 01      02          3,50                7,00        Em Proc    editar

Nº Pedido     Solicitante          Data Criacao   Data Atualizacao
      2            Fornecedor 04       23/05/2014        27/05/2014
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descrição     Qntd     Valor Uni     Valor Total         Status       #
Produto 01      02          3,50                7,00        Em Proc    editar
Produto 03      01          3,50                3,50        Em Proc    editar
```

Porém os pedidos estão se repetindo, todos os pedidos de ID dois são listados com seus produtos, e não apenas 1 Pedido de ID 2 e embaixo os produtos relacionados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Várias coisas pra corrigir:

### 1. Controller

```
public ActionResult TodosOsPedidos()
{
    var pedido = _db.Pedidos.Include(p => p.ProdutosPedidos).ToList();
    return View(pedido);
}
```

Certifique-se que há no cabeçalho a declaração `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Evite selecionar pela associação.

### 2. View

Repare que aqui mudo o `@model` para `IEnumerable<Pedido>` pra iteração ficar mais intuitiva.

Faltou iterar os pedidos:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 85px">
                Pedido Nº
            </th>
            <th style="text-align: left">
                Solicitante
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Data do Pedido
            </th>
            <th style="width: 120px">
                Atualizado Em
            </th>

            <th style="width: 65px"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) // Model é IEnumerable<Pedido>
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Franqueado.NomeFantasia)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Produtos", new { @id = item.PedidoId })" title="Editar" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary tool">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="@item.PedidoId" title="Excluir" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger tool delete-produto">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%"  colspan="5">
                <h5>Produtos</h5>
                <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Descrição</th>
                            <th>Quantidade</th>
                            <th>Valor Unitário</th>
                            <th>Valor Total</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var produtoPedido in item.ProdutosPedidos)
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => produtoPedido.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => produtoPedido.Quantidade)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => produtoPedido.Produto.Valor)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => produtoPedido.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => produtoPedido.Produto.Descricao)</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Na parte "p => p.ProdutosPedidos.Produto" o "ProdutosPedidos" fica vermelho e ao passar o mouse em cima da a seguinte mensagem: "Cannot resolve simbol 'ProdutosPedidos' Code is unreacheble"

Comment: @HermesAutran Então tem alguma coisa errada no seu relacionamento em código. Se o ReSharper indica a propriedade em vermelho, significa que `ProdutosPedidos` não existe no *Model* `Pedido`.

Comment: As minhas classes estão como acima. =/

Comment: @HermesAutran Colocou `using System.Data.Entity` no cabeçalho do seu *Controller*?

Comment: Funcionou, o `ProdutosPedidos` está ok, mas o `Produto` ficou vermelho.

Comment: Verdade, porque é `IEnumerable`. Use apenas `Include(p => p.ProdutosPedidos)`. Vou arrumar a resposta.

Comment: No `@foreach (var produtoPedido in Model.ProdutosPedidos)` o `ProdutosPedidos` aparece a mesma mensagem `Cannot resolve simbol 'ProdutosPedidos'`

Comment: Você mudou o `@model IEnumerable<Pedido>` conforme eu descrevi na resposta?

Comment: Sim, está certo aqui na `View` --> `@model IEnumerable<Pedido>`

Comment: Erro meu. Troque `@foreach (var produtoPedido in Model.ProdutosPedidos)` por `@foreach (var produtoPedido in item.ProdutosPedidos)`. Vou alterar novamente a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu queria, porem os dados dos produtos estão vindo em branco.

Comment: Agora é com você. Não sei como estão seus dados.

Comment: Adicionei o seguinte `p => p.ProdutosPedidos.Select(x => x.Produto)` e funcionou perfeitamente. Seria legal até você editar para ficar completo. Muito obrigado Morrison!